# How to exclude occurrences after a positive lookbehind?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, regex-group

Suppose I have the following `markdown` list items:

```markdown
- [x] Example of a completed task.
- [x] ! Example of a completed task.
- [x] ? Example of a completed task.
```

I am interested to parse that item using `regex` and extract the following group captures:

- `$1`: the left `[` and the right `]` brackets when the symbol `x` is in-between
- `$2`: the symbol `x` in between the brackets `[` and `]`
- `$3`: the modifier `!` that follows after `[x]`
- `$4`: the modifier `?` that follows after `[x]`
- `$5`: the text that follows `[x]` without a modifier, e.g., `[x] This is targeted.`
- `$6`: the text that follows `[x] !`
- `$7`: the text that follows `[x] ?`

After a lot of trial-and-error using online parsers, I came up with the following:

```regex
((?<=x)\]|\[(?=x]))|((?<=\[)x(?=\]))|((?<=\[x\]\s)!(?=\s))|((?<=\[x\]\s)\?(?=\s))|((?<=\[x\]\s)[^!?].*)|((?<=\[x\]\s!\s).*)|((?<=\[x\]\s\?\s).*)
```

To make the `regex` above more readable, these are the capture groups listed one by one:

- `$1`: `((?<=x)\]|\[(?=x]))`
- `$2`: `((?<=\[)x(?=\]))`
- `$3`: `((?<=\[x\]\s)!(?=\s))`
- `$4`: `((?<=\[x\]\s)\?(?=\s))`
- `$5`: `((?<=\[x\]\s)[^!?].*)`
- `$6`: `((?<=\[x\]\s!\s).*)`
- `$7`: `((?<=\[x\]\s\?\s).*)`

This is most likely not the best way to do it, but at least it seems to capture what I want:

[image: Matches for the example list items]

I would like to extend that `regex` to capture lines in a `markdown` table that
looks like this:

```markdown
|       | Task name                               |    Plan     |   Actual    |      File      |
| :---- | :-------------------------------------- | :---------: | :---------: | :------------: |
| [x]   | Task one with a reasonably long name.   | 08:00-08:45 | 08:00-09:00 |  [[task-one]]  |
| [x] ! | Task two with a reasonably long name.   | 09:00-09:30 |             |  [[task-two]]  |
| [x] ? | Task three with a reasonably long name. | 11:00-13:00 |             | [[task-three]] |
```

More specifically, I am interested in having the same group captures as above, but I would like to exclude the table grid (i.e., the `|`). So, groups `$1` to `$4` should stay the same, but groups `$5` to `$7` should capture the text, excluding the `|`, e.g., like in the selection below:

[image: Matches for the example table]

Do you have any ideas on how I can adjust, for example, the regex for group `$5` to exclude the `|`. I have endlessly tried all sorts of negations (e.g., `[^\|]`). I am using [Oniguruma regular expressions](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#textmate-grammars).

Comment: For getting the column values you could do: https://regex101.com/r/kRIonQ/1   (regex: `((?<=\|)[^|]*)` )

Comment: "but groups `$5` to `$7` should capture the text, excluding the `|`" - I don't believe it is possible for a capture group to be made up from a sequence of non-contiguous characters. It would be best to capture these as additional separate groups or post-process after capture.

Comment: @DeanTaylor, I think you have very clearly formulated what I was trying to do, i.e., *to create a capture group from a sequence of non-contiguous characters*. Unfortunately, I cannot do any post-processing as the `regex` above is part of a grammar injection in VSCode.

Comment: @Luuk, this seems interesting. If I understand correctly, you were able to create a single group while excluding the `|`. I will play around with it.

Comment: @DeanTaylor, this combination `(?<=\|).*?(?=\|)` of positive lookbehind and positive lookahead seems to allow me to select everything in between adjacent pairs of `|` as a single group. Now I have to figure out how to exclude the pairs of `|` that contain `| [x] |`.

Comment: Try `((?<=x)\]|\[(?=x]))|((?<=\[)x(?=\]))|((?<=\[x\]\s)!(?=\s))|(?<=\[x\]\s)(\?)(?=\s)|(?<=x].*?\|)(.*?)(?=\|)` if you are using the regex engine used in open document Search and Replace feature. See https://regex101.com/r/XBFkp2/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I greatly appreciate that you took the time to look at this question! I focused on the `(?<=x].*?\|)(.*?)(?=\|)` part from the `regex` you wrote, and I see that the `*?` inside the positive lookbehind makes it non-fixed width. As per the documentation, the *pattern must have a fixed width*. About the engine, I am using [Oniguruma regular expressions](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#textmate-grammars).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```rb
((?<=x)]|\[(?=x]))|((?<=\[)x(?=]))|((?<=\[x]\s)!(?=\s))|(?<=\[x]\s)(\?)(?=\s)|(?:\G(?!\A)\||(?<=\[x]\s[?!\s]\s\|))\K([^|\n]*)(?=\|)
```

See the [regex101 PCRE](https://regex101.com/r/XBFkp2/3) and a [Ruby (Onigmo/Oniguruma) demos](https://rubular.com/r/FMCmWHAjc7ZCCB).

**What is added?** The `(?:\G(?!\A)\||(?<=\[x]\s[?!\s]\s\|))\K([^|\n]*)(?=\|)` part:

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group (a custom boundary here, we'll match...)

  - `\G(?!\A)\|` - either the end of the previous match and a `|` char (i.e. `|` must immediately follow the previous match),
  - `|(?<=\[x]\s[?!\s]\s\|)` - or a location that is immediately preceded with `[x]` + a whitespace + a `?`, `!` or whitespace + a whitespace and `|` char
- `)` - end of the group
- `\K` - match reset operator that removes the text matched so far from the overall match memory buffer
- `([^|\n]*)` - zero or more chars other than `|` and a line feed char
- `(?=\|)` - a `|` char must appear immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: I am thoroughly studying your solution and will report back!

Comment: It took me a while to wrap my head around `\G`, `\A` and `\K`, but I can confirm that this works splendidly. The only thing is that when I try to create my capture groups, the `\K` seems to be ignored. For example, trying to match `b` and capture it as group `$1` (i.e., not `$0`) in string `ab` using `regex` `(a\Kb)` will match `ab`.

Comment: @Mihai `\K` only affects the "**overall match** memory buffer", it does not affec captured texts.

Comment: I got really confused about it and I ended asking a follow-up question here (i.e., https://stackoverflow.com/q/70237510/5252007). The idea is that I want to use your solution in a capture group and things become a bit hard to understand… You helped a lot and I can stress enough how much I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the answer by [Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) , check the following regex, which is quite short

```
(?:\G(?<!\A)\||(?:\[x]\s[?!]?\s*\|?))\K([^|\n]*)
```

The explanation to above

```
1.\G(?!\A)\|
```

> **\G** asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match. Negative Lookbehind **(?!\A)**
>
> 1. \A asserts position at start of the string
> 2. | matches the character |

2. `(?:\[x]\s[?!]?\s*\|?)`

> Non-capturing group. That matches [x], \s (space), [?|!] (zero or 1) followed by \s* (zero or more) and a | (zero or one)

3. `\K`

> \K resets the starting point of the reported match.

4. `([^|\n]*)`

> All characters **except** | or \n (newline) matches previous token zero or unlimited times.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! With the expression you indicated, the first `|` gets omitted, but subsequent ones are not. For example, in a construction of this form `| [x]   | Task one with a reasonably long name.   | 08:00-08:45 | 08:00-09:00 |  [[task-one]]  |`, I would like everything else but the `[x]` and `|` to be matched as a single group, while preserving the other groups I indicated in the question above.

Comment: I am sorry, but this is not what I am looking for. I am interested to maintain all the seven group captures. With the `regex` you mentioned I get only one *incorrect* group capture, as shown here: https://regex101.com/r/NOuTOb/1.

Comment: Maybe I'm getting your requirement wrong. One last clarification

Comment: Maybe I am not explaining it clearly enough. I updated my question in the hope that the outcome will be more clear. Also, these are the groups and requirements: https://regex101.com/r/81Jc8a/1 (i.e., see *Description*).

Comment: Updated answer, can be checked at https://regex101.com/r/5OaZc0/1

Comment: Yes, it gets the job done! I still find it hard to wrap my head around `\G(?!\A)\`. I accepted @Wiktor's answer as it was more timely, but I nevertheless appreciate your help! I noticed that when a capturing group is added around an expression that contains `\K`, the reset match is no longer respected.

Comment: Thank you for the nice question and also @Wiktor. Got a good deal to learn

Comment: I subscribe to that---I also have a lot to learn. I spent most of my weekend fiddling with your answer and @Wiktor's. I've learned about the `\K`, and now I am trying to see how to use it in conjunction with a capture group (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/q/70237510/5252007).